# Connecting to a container via localhost: Docker vs Kubernetes

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am new to cloud technology and trying to learn docker and kubernetes. I recently dockerized a spring boot app which was using mongodb for persistence. First I started a mongodb container using the docker run command and mapped the port 27017(default port used by spring data for mongo db) and then started the app locally on intellij, everything worked fine. Then I created a docker compose file and put both of these together and it didn't work(got a connection exception to mongodb). Ultimately I had to set the host of mongodb which springboot was looking for to the host of the mongodb container started by docker(both defined within the docker-compose file) as an environment variable and then it worked.

My question is why the app could connect to mongodb via localhost from outside of container(running on intellij), but not from inside?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that while each docker container can be reached from the host's network, they can only reach each other **via their local ip addresses**. "localhost" *inside* docker no longer means what it does to us *outside* docker, because DNS will not resolve 'localhost' to the host, inside docker.

Determining the individual ip addresses of each container just to establish communication between them is a bit of a pain, so make use of **user-defined networks** instead. To quote from docker:

> User-defined bridges provide automatic DNS resolution between 
>   containers.

Have a look at these links for further detail:

- https://docs.docker.com/network/
- https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/

Answer (score 1):

Docker manages its own network in your machine. When you start two containers they are effectively isolated from the rest of the world and more Importantly, they are isolated from each other. It is as if they were running in different machines

In order for the containers to talk to each other, you normally need to create a new docker network and attach the two containers to that network (like attaching two machines two a  network switch). As such, trying to talk to another container using localhost does not work because they are viewed as two different entities.

Docker-compose makes the whole process simpler because it automatically creates the docker network and attaches the all the containers defined in docker-compose.yml to that docker network. You can do `docker network inspect` before and after running `docker-compose` and you will see the new network come up. When you do docker-compose down, the containers are automatically detached from that network and the network is deleted.

[Here](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/) is some documentation about docker networks